# How to write multi dimensional Array to DataGridView

Tags: c#

How can I load a Data from XML file to DataGridView like the table below:

```
y\x  [0,0]          0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 
y\x  [10,10]    0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 
y\x  [20,20]    0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 
y\x  [30,30]    0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 
y\x  [40,40]    0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563 0.000976563
```

The structure of my XML file is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
        <Tag>
          <Parameter>
            <Name>Parameter1</Name>
            <Size_X>7</Size_X>
            <Size_Y>2</Size_Y>
            <Value_X>0;2;8;12;14;16;19;</Value_X>
            <Value_Y>-20;-10;</Value_Y>

<Value>0000000000000;5.0000000000000000;10.0000000000000000;15.0000000000000000;20.0000000000000000;25.0000000000000000;0000000000000;5.0000000000000000;10.0000000000000000;15.0000000000000000;20.0000000000000000;25.0000000000000000;</Value>
          </Parameter1>
          <Parameter2>
            <Name>Parameter2</Name>
            <Size_X>7</Size_X>
            <Size_Y>3</Size_Y>
            <Value_X>0;2;4;6;8;10;12;</Value_X>
            <Value_Y>20;40;60;</Value_Y>
<Value>0000000000000;5.0000000000000000;10.0000000000000000;15.0000000000000000;20.0000000000000000;30.0000000000000000;     0000000000000;5.0000000000000000;10.0000000000000000;15.0000000000000000;20.0000000000000000;30.0000000000000000;0000000000000;5.0000000000000000;10.0000000000000000;15.0000000000000000;20.0000000000000000;30.0000000000000000;</Value>
              </Parameter2>
            </Tag>
```

I Have tried the next code, but it does not work:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Write.xml");
            var variables = from variable in xmlDoc.Descendants("Parameter")
                            where variable.Element("Name").Value == "Parameter1"
                            select new
                            {
                                Name = variable.Element("Name").Value,
                                SizeX = variable.Element("Size_X").Value,
                                SizeY = variable.Element("Size_Y").Value,
                                ValueX = variable.Element("Value_X").Value,
                                ValueY = variable.Element("Value_Y").Value,
                                Value = variable.Element("Value").Value,
                            };

            foreach (var variable in variables)
            {

                var x = Convert.ToInt32(variable.SizeX);
                var y = Convert.ToInt32(variable.SizeY);
                dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "y/x";

                var arr = new double[y, x];//{Value} it must be the value here???
                var columnCount = arr.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
                var rowCount = arr.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), variable.ValueX);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i.ToString(),variable.ValueY);
                    for (int k = 0; k < columnCount; k++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Value = arr[i, k];
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article [Binding a two dimensional array to a DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5806/Binding-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-DataGrid) will give you some insight. 
Basically:

```
//
// 1. Create two dimensional array
//
const int  dim = 1000;

double[,]  array = new double[dim,dim];

Random ran = new Random();
for(int r = 0; r < dim; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < dim; c++)
    {
        array[r,c] = (ran.Next(dim)); // fill it with random numbers.
    }
}

// 2. Create ArrayDataView class in which 
// constructor you pass the array 
// and assign it to DataSource property of DataGrid. 

 dataGrid1.DataSource = new ArrayDataView(array);
```

or you can try:

```
var data = new double[5,5]
{
    { 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563 },
    { 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563 },
    { 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563 },
    { 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563, 0.000976563 },
};

var rowCount = data.GetLength(0);
var rowLength = data.GetLength(1);

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; ++rowIndex)
{
    var row = new DataGridViewRow();

    for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < rowLength; ++columnIndex)
    {
        row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
            {
                Value = data[rowIndex, columnIndex]
            });
    }

    dataGrid1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Whats ArrayDataView? Ive never seen this.

Comment: It's a custom type which represent view of the multidimensional array data.

Comment: Ah right. Seems a bit excessive to use this for such a simple task and doesn't teach the asker how to actually do it.

Comment: The first example I admit is a bit overkill for such a simple operation but for complex data perhaps that will suffice. I have edited my answer to provide a simple approach.

Answer (score 1):

First add your columns and rows then populate the cells

```
var arr = new int[5, 3];  // array is just for example
var columnCount = arr.GetUpperBound(1)+1;
var rowCount = arr.GetUpperBound(0)+1;

for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(i.ToString()," ");
}
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.AddCopy(0);
    for (int k = 0; k < columnCount; k++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Value = arr[i, k];
    }

}
```